# How does a transistor work in an electric circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

For example, if this is the circuit containing the transistor:
[image]

The positive holes move to the right hand plate of the collector.  The electrons must be moving in the opposite direction from the wire onto the plate. So do the holes get filled with electrons? If so, what happens next? if not, what is the correct explanation?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, could you clarify it ?

Comment: I wanted to know what happens at the electron level when a transistor is connected in an electric circuit. I know that because of the forward biasing at the BE junction and reverse biasing at the BC junction, the positive holes travel towards Collector plate. Since current is shown to be flowing from the Collector plate into the wire attached to it, electrons must be flowing from the wire to the Collector plate. If so, do the positive holes and electrons recombine?

Comment: Since the material is P-type they should recombine when they enter the medium. This is of course under the assumption that the current depicted on other parts of the schematic is also valid, as we have charge conservation.